# Symfony3.3: autowire a controller with scalar argument

Tags: symfony

The my controller contains an action with an scalar dependency `$bugReportRecipient`.

```
class DefaultController
{
    public function bugReportAction(SwiftTwigMailer $swiftTwigMailer, string $bugReportRecipient, Request $request)
    {
        // more code
    }
}
```

My service definition looks like this:

```
AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController:
    autowire: true
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

If I run the action this error is shown:

`Controller "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::bugReportAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$bugReportRecipient" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.`

How can I inject this argument? I haven't found any helpful in the symfony documentation so far.

[EDIT]:

The argument `$bugReportRecipient` is parameter which is defined in my `parameters.yml`.

Comment: public function bugReportAction(SwiftTwigMailer $swiftTwigMailer,  $bugReportRecipient, Request $request) just without string

Comment: no, get the same error.

Comment: Why are you using $bugReportRecipient?

Comment: I have removed all `->get()` and `->getParameter()` in my action, so I have to inject my dependencies.

Comment: Can you remove  `$bugReportRecipient` argument from `function`?

Comment: Without this parameter it works but I need this dependency in my action

Comment: Where is from getting this argument? from your service?

Comment: I didn't know it's possibile since Symfony 3.3, sorry. Have you tried to define your scalar dependency as a parameter?

Comment: I have a feeling that this new feature is not meant to be used this way.  If `bugReportAction` is receiving an ID, then, perhaps you could use `ParamConverter` to get the `bugReportRecipient` entity?

Comment: `bugReportRecipient` is a simple parameter defined in my `parameters.yml`. Sorry I haven't mentioned it.

Comment: From: http://symfony.com/doc/master/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html "If you have an argument that is not an object, it can't be autowired."  It goes on to explain how to manually configure just that one argument but the example is for a constructor.  Not sure if you can do it for an action method.  Be curious to find out.  I suppose a real hack would be to go ahead and create a simple bug report recipient object.

Comment: This might also help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services-as-controller-arguments Looks like you can explicitly specify arguments to particular action.

Comment: @Cerad this works only for services. If 'id' is an DI parameter then a ServiceNotFoundException will be thrown.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  Not a big fan of the whole autowire concept anyways.  Might want to poke around on github and see if there are any relevant issues.  Or maybe ask a question here: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3 Tomas is very knowledgeable about the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the action comes from the same place as before - you either set a default value in the function definition, or at least have a value given by the route, which might be set like such:

```
* @Route("/bug-report/{bugReportRecipient}", name="bugreport", 
*        defaults={"bugReportRecipient" = "username"})
```

The `SwiftTwigMailer` is injected because of the `controller.service_arguments` tag in the same way as `Request` has been before.

Note - you can still set a variable's default value in the @Route for a variable that does not appear in the {URL} part - but it has to be set somewhere.

I've used this technique for setting different values for a variable based on the specific route that is being used.

```
 * @Route("/",         name="homepage_menus", 
 *        defaults={"hasMenus"=true, "partnerLinks"=false})
 * @Route("/partners", name="homepage_partner_footer", 
 *        defaults={"hasMenus"=false,"partnerLinks"=true})
```

Neither of these variables (they also have defaults already set in the function definition) can appear in the URL, but are set based on the route that is used.

---

If the $bugReportRecipient is a parameter, it can be set in the service definition like such:

```
arguments:
    $bugReportRecipient: "%kernel.environment%" # or whatever
```

There does not appear to be a way to set it on the action level, and so you will have to make the controller a more formal service, and set at least this parameter on the class-level.

You may also be able to use the Expression language to do this.

```
services:
    AppBundle\Mailer:
        arguments: ["@=container.hasParameter('some_param') ? parameter('some_param') : 'default_value'"]
```

Comment: the `bugReportRecipient ` parameter comes from the service-container, so it has nothing to do with my route definition